# Google OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wanted to access GCP storage bucket from outside. So I used following steps which google has provided.

1. Created the service account
2. Generated the jwt token using the private key that provided for service account.

[image]

When I called the above API to get access token by providing jwt token it gives following error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "Empty or missing scope not allowed."
}
```

Thanks in advance!

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

This is the Java code I used to generate the JWT

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

try {

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("service.json"));
    PrivateKey privateKey = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey();
    String privateKeyId = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId();

    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey);
    String signedJwt = JWT.create()
        .withKeyId(privateKeyId)
        .withIssuer("***********@************-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
        .withSubject("***********@************-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
        .withAudience("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
        .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
        .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 3600 * 1000L))
        .sign(algorithm);

    System.out.println(signedJwt);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Show your code on how you are creating the Signed-JWT and the Scopes that you specified. I wrote an article detailing how to create an Access Token from a service account in Python: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: @JohnHanley this is how I generated the jwt token

Comment: Edit your question and format your code so that we can read it.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you very much for the help. I went through your article and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out the issue. It was with the payload that I passed to generate the JWT token. 
Below I attched the python code which I used to genarate jwt token. 
I got the reference from  https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/ below python code

```
import jwt
import time

# Permissions to request for Access Token
scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"

# private key id
pkey_id = ""

# private key
pkey = ""

serviceid = ""

# Google Endpoint for creating OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens from Signed-JWT
auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

# Set how long this token will be valid in seconds
expires_in = 3600  # Expires in 1 hour

issued = int(time.time())
expires = issued + expires_in  # expires_in is in seconds

# JWT Payload
payload = {
    "iss": serviceid,   # Issuer claim
    "sub": serviceid,   # Issuer claim
    "aud": auth_url,    # Audience claim
    "iat": issued,      # Issued At claim
    "exp": expires,     # Expire time
    "scope": scopes     # Permissions
}

# JWT Headers
additional_headers = {
    'kid': pkey_id,
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT"  # Google uses SHA256withRSA
}

sig = jwt.encode(payload, pkey, algorithm="RS256", headers=additional_headers)
print(sig)
```

Comment: You can Generate private_key_id and private_key (pkey_id, pkey) for given service id through GCP IAM & Admin > Service account > Create Key (Action column)